# Spring MVC: triggering and terminating a backend method by turning on and off a switch on a web page

Tags: java, ajax, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc

So in the front end main page, there is an switch which I can turn on and off. The state code of the switch can be sent using Ajax to the back end.

Now, when the switch is turned on, I want the back end method to keep running, which I defined as follows:

```
public static void foo {

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(8000);
                    ArticleDAO.addNewArticles();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

And when the switched is turned off, I want the method, or the thread to be terminated.

The Ajax code in JSP page looks like this:

```
$("#switcher").on("switchChange.bootstrapSwitch", function(e, state) {
    if (state == true) {

        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/wx/admin/toggle_state.html",
                data: {
                    stateCode: 1
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Switched to auto mode");
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Something went wrong!!");
                }
            });
        });

    } else if (state == false) {

        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/wx/admin/toggle_state.html",
                data: {
                    stateCode: 0
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Switched to manual mode");
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Something went wrong!!");
                }
            });
        });

    } else {
        alert("Something went wrong!!");
    }
});
```

And here's the spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "admin/toggle_state.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String toggleState(@RequestParam Integer stateCode) throws Exception {
    if (stateCode == 1) {
        /*

        EXECUTE THE FOO METHOD RIGHT HERE

        */
        System.out.println("Switched to auto mode.");
    } else if (stateCode == 0) {
        // TERMINATE THE METHOD / THREAD HERE
    }
    return "";
}
```

So what is the recommended way to achieve this? It actually doesn't seem too hard but I don't know how to start and terminate the thread in my situation. One way that I can think of is to store the state code of the switch to the database and make the method to check the database every time the method runs in the thread. But it doesn't seem to be a good solution to this. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a bean (application scope) to keep a reference to the thread.  Autowire the bean to the controller.

Check the stateCode value and use the reference of bean to start()/stop() the thread.

```
@Component
public ThreadHolderBean {
  Thread theThreadReference=new Thread();//init the thread properly
}
```

Now in your controler just  add

```
@Autowired 
private ThreadHolderBean threadHolder;
```

And use the threadHolder in the toggleState() method

If you need multiple threads e.g for each session change the bean scope or define a Thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

Threads can be interrupted, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using Spring, then [TaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) 
is a perfect fit for this Scenario, with that you be able to use the underlying methods like  `ExecutorService.shutdown(), ExecutorService.shutdownNow(), awaitTerminationIfNecessary()

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this from the controller...

```
public static void foo(int stateCodeFromFrontEnd) {

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int stateCode = stateCodeFromFrontEnd;
        while(stateCode == 1) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(8000);
                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    stateCode = 0;
                }
                ArticleDAO.addNewArticles();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});

thread.start();
}
```

And when your switch is turned off, call the thread.interrupt().

Comment: Thanks but how do I get the reference to that thread when the switched is turned off?

Comment: You can do it by creating the thread as the instance variable.